# Working backwards from compiled Webpack pages

Tags: debugging, webpack, reverse-engineering

I'm working on a react project that uses webpack to compile the code. It works fine overall, except that there is this strange bit of HTML at the bottom of every page. No one who is working on the project knows where it has come from.

What is strange is that the outputted text cannot be found in any of the project's source code, even within the files that webpack has compiled.

I'm supposing that therefore this HTML must come from some JavaScript that's putting it out. Either way though, that's not my main question. My main question is, when looking at a webpage that is compiled by webpack, are there any tools or steps that one could take to find out where this compiled code is coming from?

(I'm hoping that even if this does not directly lead to the solution my problem, it will help me to get closer to the solution)

Comment: Try enabling sourcemaps?

Comment: @Doug is there way to do this for HTML? (I'm not sure what JavaScript causes this, I only see the HTML output)